# React Native build fails with "compileSdkVersion is not specified" message

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, android-sdk-2.3

I have created a fresh React Native project using `expo init RNCourse-Bare`, I'm following expo bare approach. I haven't changed anything in the project, just tried to run it against Virtual Device using `npm run android --info` command, here's my output:

[image]

And here's my `.bash_profile`:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export PATH=$PATH:ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

And here's my Virtual Device:

[image]

Also, I have 2 versions of SDK installed:

- android-31
- android-33-ext

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my laptop solved the issue